# Gulp: Create HTML from template and inject

Tags: gulp, vagrant

I'm creating HTMLs to inject there revisioned sources from templates as **file.html.tpl**.

So I have **css.html.tpl** which has following:

```
<!-- common:css -->
<!-- endinject -->

<!-- vendor:css -->
<!-- endinject -->

<!-- custom:css -->
<!-- endinject -->
```

and using this function which read that **.html.tpl** file Sync, then write in **.html** the template

```
exports.createHTMLfromTemplate = function (distDir, templateFileNames) {
  for(var i = 0; i < templateFileNames.length; i++) {
    var file = templateFileNames[i];
    var tplData = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, file));
    var distPath = path.join(distDir, file.slice(0, -4)); // remove .tpl

    fs.writeFile(distPath, tplData, function (err) {
      if (err) log(exports.error(err));
    });

  }
};
```

and then we should have ready **.html** files with those comments to inject, then we inject our revisioned files.

```
gulp.task('inject-js', function () {
  var distPath = path.join(__dirname, paths.baseSrc)
  helper.createHTMLfromTemplate(distPath, 'js.html.tpl')
  var injected = gulp.src(distPath + 'js.html');

  _.each(jsTasks, function (task) {
    var injector = task.filename.substr(0, task.filename.length - 3);
    var gulpSrc = gulp.src(task.paths.dest + injector + '*.js', {read: false});
    injected
      .pipe($gulp.inject(gulpSrc, {name: injector}))
  });

  return injected
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.baseSrc))
    .on('error', helper.handleError);
});
```

the result in **js.html** is following:

```
<!-- common:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/dist/common-fee68d20.css">
<!-- endinject -->

<!-- vendor:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/dist/vendor-7cd25cb9.css">
<!-- endinject -->

<!-- custom:css -->
<!-- endinject -->
```

as you can see, if I run this gulp inside of Vagrant (VM), it will not inject in some comments, when running outside Vagrant, e.g. using local gulp, it injects properly.

Why? :)

Comment: are you asking why is gulp-inject working only partially in a vagrant environment?

Comment: @WilmerSaint, Yes, in local (outside of VM) it works as expected

Comment: VM is on Ubuntu, my local OS is Windows 7 - it if matters...

Comment: I added an answer as it was too long for a comment, but it isn't really an answer. Just some steps to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Full disclosure*: *I have not used Vagrant*

Maybe we can narrow it down. [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) works on the given glob path and:

> takes a stream of source files, transforms each file to a string and
>   injects each transformed string into placeholders in the target stream
>   files.

If the injection is not taking place, then my first though is that it is not finding the files that it needs to inject.

Try using something like [gulp-debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-debug) to see if the files that need to be injected actually make it into the pipe stream.

If in the Vagrant environment you are getting the files from source control instead of mapping to the same path as your local dev environment then it should work. Otherwise the vinyl paths may not be resolving to the correct directory.

The puzzling part is that it works, but only partially. If it is not a path issue and you are using reved files then the task responsible for generating the `<!-- custom:css -->` may be the culprit. That would make more sense.

**EDIT**

---

A note from gulp-inject:

> Note: As of gulp-inject v4.0.0, NodeJS v4 or above is required. To use
>   gulp-inject for older versions of Node install a specific version: npm
>   install gulp-inject@3.

I have no reason to think that this may be the problem, but just in case cross check the Node version number in your local and VM environments.

Comment: thanks. I resolved the issue yesterday. I used to run gulp tasks (with concat, uglify, rev) in for-each loop. Then call gulp inject with the same for-each. So I decided to split tasks as the separate gulp.task, not execute them in for-each, and it worked. But they is a lot of copy-paste now, but for now it's ok for me. Seems, it is what you were talkin about regarding Vinyl Paths. And +1 for gulp-debug, it gave me a good hint.